# Regex code stopped working for no reason

Tags: c++, netbeans

Here's the code that I'm trying to build and compile. I'm not sure what I did, but this code **worked before** (a couple of weeks ago).

```
#include <regex>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    regex txt_regex("[a-z]+\\.txt");
    return 0;
}
```

Here's the **error log** from netbeans:

```
cd '/home/dev/Desktop/test'
/usr/bin/make -f Makefile CONF=Debug
"/usr/bin/make" -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk QMAKE= SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/dev/Desktop/test'
"/usr/bin/make"  -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk dist/Debug/GNU-Linux/test
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/dev/Desktop/test'
mkdir -p build/Debug/GNU-Linux
rm -f "build/Debug/GNU-Linux/main.o.d"
g++    -c -g -std=c++11 -MMD -MP -MF "build/Debug/GNU-Linux/main.o.d" -o build/Debug/GNU-Linux/main.o main.cpp
In file included from /usr/include/c++/5/regex:60:0,
                 from main.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/regex_compiler.h: In member function ‘bool std::__detail::_AnyMatcher<_TraitsT, false, __icase, __collate>::operator()(std::__detail::_AnyMatcher<_TraitsT, false, __icase, __collate>::_CharT) const [with _TraitsT = std::__cxx11::regex_traits<char>; bool __icase = true; bool __collate = false; std::__detail::_AnyMatcher<_TraitsT, false, __icase, __collate>::_CharT = char]’:
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/regex_compiler.h:292:7: internal compiler error: Segmentation fault
       operator()(_CharT __ch) const
       ^
Please submit a full bug report,
with preprocessed source if appropriate.
See <file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-5/README.Bugs> for instructions.
nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk:66: recipe for target 'build/Debug/GNU-Linux/main.o' failed
make[2]: *** [build/Debug/GNU-Linux/main.o] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/dev/Desktop/test'
nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk:59: recipe for target '.build-conf' failed
make[1]: *** [.build-conf] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/dev/Desktop/test'
nbproject/Makefile-impl.mk:39: recipe for target '.build-impl' failed
make: *** [.build-impl] Error 2

BUILD FAILED (exit value 2, total time: 1s)
```

**What's going on?**

Comment: Compiles just fine with VS2015.

Comment: "internal compiler error" doesn't look like this one's not on you, bub. What g++ version are you using? In a command prompt type `g++ -v` and hit enter. Somewhere in the output, usually at the bottom, should be the version number . Target, up near the top, is also helpful. Have you changed compilers recently?

Comment: @user4581301, here's g++ version `gcc version 5.4.0 20160609 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.9)`. I don't think I messed with compilers much recently.

Comment: An internal compiler error means that the compiler got totally lost. That's a compiler bug, and that's why the message asks you to submit a bug report. But that doesn't mean that there isn't a problem in your code; it just means that the compiler couldn't cope with whatever you did. The code might be okay, or it might not.

Answer (score 0):

The code works again after I updated my system:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```